# Объявление нескольких переменных в цикле for

Tags: c++

Как объявить несколько переменных в цикле for? Пытаюсь так, но не получается:

```
std::vector<int> vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (auto it = vector.cbegin(), std::size_t el_index = 0; it != vector.cend(); ++el_index, ++it) {
  std::cout << el_index << " - " << *it;
}
```

Comment: Как вариант, объявляйте их снаружи. А то у вас строчка `for` и так разрослась до неприличного размера. [Анг вариант вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866012/is-there-a-way-to-define-variables-of-two-different-types-in-a-for-loop-initiali/889062#889062)

Comment: @VTT точно, можно через структуру, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете объявлять переменные только одного и того же типа. Так что вам требуется изменить код следующим образом, чтобы он заработал:

```
std::vector<int> vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::size_t el_index = 0;
for (auto it = vector.cbegin(); it != vector.cend(); ++el_index, ++it) {
  std::cout << el_index << " - " << *it;
}
```

но для вашей реализации достаточно такого кода:

```
std::vector<int> vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (std::size_t el_index = 0; el_index < vector.size(); ++el_index) {
  std::cout << el_index << " - " << vector.at(el_index) << std::endl;
}
```